# bash loop check command error then reiterate

Tags: bash, shell

Hi i'm writing a bash script that have to keep some installation process quick and easy for non dev-user.

I wrote this loop that has to check if the command `sudo add-apt-repository` give the error `sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found` and if so, need to run the command `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` then reiterate the first command and go on with other instrucion

```
until sudo add-apt-repository; do
    echo "sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found"
    sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
done
...
other command
```

I tryed that loop but it don't run the second command under the echo. Can please someone help me fix that problem?

Thanks

Comment: Is `echo "sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found"` displayed? (do you have DOS line endings in your script?)

Comment: My mistake, i don't want to print that message on the launch of the script. That error is displayed in the terminal ssh of my vps when i first run the command sudo add-apt-repository.

Comment: No, no... I get that, I am asking when you reach the `until sudo add-apt-repository; do` line, if `sudo add-apt-repository` returns an error condition are you seeing `"sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found"` as you expect and `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` just not running? Or are you never seeing `"sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found"` when you expect you should?

Comment: If your script has been "near" MS-Windows, check for `\r\n` line endings with `cat -vet myScript | head -10`. If you see `^M$` at the end of each line, cleanup file with `dos2unix myScript`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Which behaviour do you have ? Because even if `add-apt-repository` is installed `sudo add-apt-repository` will fail

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository
Error: need a repository as argument
$ echo $?
1
```

Maybe, using "which" command is better, it returns 0 if the command exists and 1 if not.

Using conditional if instead of until should be enough to install the command.